# Add/remove to decimal places for greater and smaller sign

Tags: c#, decimal, data-conversion

I want to convert `string` values to `decimal`. When there is a smaller or greater symbol I want to add/remove to the value like this

```
string value  |  decimal result
--------------|----------------
 "< 0.22"     |   0.219
 "< 32.45"    |   32.449
 "> 2.0"      |   2.01
 "> 5"        |   5.1
```

This has to work for decimal numbers with any number of decimal places. Is there an elegant way to do this?

I can only think of counting the number of decimal places, getting the last  digit, adding/removing ...

Comment: This seems like it is a homework/learning exercise. Can you show what you have tried? (Hint: start by separating the value from the inequality, and then parse the value.)

Comment: Homework - are you kidding me?

Comment: Any number of decimal places - does this include zero (e.g. `32`)? (I think your idea of counting the number of decimal places is likely to be the most robust and simplest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                "< 0.22",
                "< 32.45",
                 "> 2.0"
                             };
            string pattern = @"(?'sign'[\<\>])\s+(?'integer'\d+).(?'fraction'\d+)";

            decimal number = 0;
            foreach(string input in inputs)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
                if(match.Groups["sign"].Value == ">")
                {
                   number = decimal.Parse(match.Groups["integer"].Value  + "." + match.Groups["fraction"].Value);
                   number += decimal.Parse("." + new string('0', match.Groups["fraction"].Value.Length) + "1");
                }
                else
                {
                   number = decimal.Parse(match.Groups["integer"].Value  + "." + match.Groups["fraction"].Value);
                   number -= decimal.Parse("." + new string('0', match.Groups["fraction"].Value.Length) + "1");
                }

                    Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems a bit overkill

Comment: It is just so much code because it is a complete runable example. Great work!

Comment: at least compile this regex and reuse it

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose the regex answer as the accepted solution? Isn't my solution both quicker and a lot less code?

Comment: You're correct. But it solves for both greater than and less in far less code and quicker than regex while solving your issue "I can only think of counting the number of decimal places, getting the last digit, adding/removing ...". But I updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 4):

So I would imagine the following solution

1. Split the string on the space
2. Identify the sign (GT or LT)
3. Count the number of decimal places and store that value
4. Convert the number to a decimal
5. Based on the symbol either add or subtract 10^(-1 * (numberOfDecimals + 1))

Answer (score 1):

Solution without counting the decimals:

If the string starts with `>`, append `"1"`. If the string starts with `<` replace the last character by the next lower one (Notice: for `"0"`->`"9"` and repeat on the character left to it) and then append `"9"`. 
Then split at the blank and `Double.Parse` the right part.

Answer (score 1):

No need to count digits or split apart the decimal... (you can run this in linqpad)

```
string inputString = "> 0.22";

string[] data = inputString.Split(' ');
double input = double.Parse(data[1]);
double gt = double.Parse(data[1] + (data[1].Contains('.') ? "1" : ".1"));

switch(data[0])
{
    case ">":
        gt.Dump(); // return gt;
        break;
    case "<":
        double lt = input - (gt - input);
        lt.Dump(); // return lt;
        break;
}

// you could even make it smaller by just doing (instead of the switch):
return data[0]==">" ? gt : input - (gt - input);
```

If trailing zeros are allowed as input but are considered insignificant then trim them.

```
inputString = inputString.TrimEnd("0");
```

Comment: This won't work because you're not counting the number of decimal places in the input string, which may be something like `0.22000`. In fact, any working solution must somehow count the number of decimal places in the input string.

Comment: I mean that if the input was `0.2200` your code will produce `0.219` and `0.221`, but it should be `0.22001` and `0.21999`. Also, try it with the OP's example of `2.0`...

Comment: Why? Trailing zeros are insignificant. If he wants them or doesn't want them, the code will work.

Comment: The trailing zeros ARE significant. They indicate the accuracy of the input data. If the input is `1.0000` it means the data is accurate to 4 decimal places, whereas if it is `1.0` it means it it's only accurate to 1 decimal place - and the expected output is different for those two cases as per my example with `0.2200`. Look at the OP's example for `2.0`. And try it with your code!

Comment: Ok. Lets walk through it. "2.0"; input = 2; gt = "2.0" + "1" = "2.01" = 2.01; lt = 2 - (2.01 - 2) = 1.99; which part is wrong? Looks correct to me

Comment: I got my +1 taken away and it actually does work. I blame you. Are you happy now?

Comment: It works now. :) Note that the number of trailing zeros IS significant, but they are accounted for because you append a `1` to them.

Comment: I corrected it after your very first comment. It's late and I'm tired so i missed the input vs inputString bug :p The other fix was for numbers that didn't have a decimal place. But as you can see it does work without counting digits. :)

Comment: Yes and I +1ed it since I think this is the best answer.